# IndexError when using Enumerated Indexes in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, numpy-ndarray, index-error

I am trying to create a fifth-order FIR filter in Python described by the following difference equation (apologies dark mode users but LaTeX is not yet supported on SO):

[image: diff_eq]

```py
def filter(x):

    h = np.array([-0.0147, 0.173, 0.342, 0.342, 0.173, -0.0147])
    y = np.zeros_like(x)

    buf_array = np.zeros_like(h)
    buf = 0.0

    for n in enumerate(x):
        for k in enumerate(h):
            buf = h[k]*x[n-k]
            buf_array[k] = buf

        y[n] = np.sum(buf_array)

    return y
```

When using the filter, the Traceback leads me to the following line:

```
     10 for n in enumerate(x):
     11     for k in enumerate(h):
---> 12         buf = h[k]*x[n-k]
     13         buf_array[k] = buf
     15     y[n] = np.sum(buf_array)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I have tried playing around with indexes and all, but have not managed to understand why this error is being caused.

TIA

Comment: `enumerate` gives indexes *and values*.

Comment: (Other problems: `x[x-k]` should say `x[n-k]`, and you're not handling accesses that run off the edges of your array correctly.)

Comment: @user2357112 You're right regarding the `x[n-k]`. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @user2357112 I come from a C background. In this case, what do you suggest, code-wise?

Comment: For this specific case, I would suggest [`scipy.signal.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html). For NumPy code in general, I would recommend avoiding Python-level loops and trying to get NumPy vectorized operations to handle as much as possible. For non-NumPy code, it's usually best to avoid indices and loop directly over the elements of a container with a plain `for` loop: `for thing in whatever`. If indexes are needed, you can loop over indexes and elements together with `for i, thing in enumerate(whatever)`.

Comment: Hi @user2357112 I tried looping over indexes and elements together with `for i, thing in enumerate(whatever)` and it works. I suggest putting this as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone suggested in the comments, this case use requires looping over indexes and elements on their own, as using `for index in enumerate(ndarray)` will result in `index` being a tuple rather than being an integer. Furthermore, using `for index, item in enumerate(ndarray)` is suggested, as shown below:

```py
# Filter function
def filter(x):

    h = np.array([-0.0147, 0.173, 0.342, 0.342, 0.173, -0.0147])
    y = np.zeros_like(x)

    buf_array = np.zeros_like(h)
    buf = 0.0

    for n, n_i in enumerate(x):
        for k, k_i in enumerate(h):
            i = n-k
            buf = h[k]*x[i]
            buf_array[k] = buf

        y[n] = np.sum(buf_array)

    return y
```